# Spacetime in Loop quantum gravity

Tags: gravity, spacetime, hamiltonian-formalism, loop-quantum-gravity, spin-models

- In [LQG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_quantum_gravity), does spacetime consist of interconnected loops?
- Are those loops real?
- If spacetime does not consist of the aforementioned loops, what it consists of?

The definition of real would be: **they physically exist**. I don't know if this helps,  but for me things that physically exist would be for example an atom, a rock, a book,.. I hope you get my meaning.

Comment: Define "real" in your second question.

Comment: As far as I know, the Wilson loops are a computational device and not intended to be a fundamental unit of spacetime. Likewise the spin networks/foams that have superceded the use of Wilson loops. I would be interested to see a definitive statement on the subject, though I don't know whether we have any LQGers amongst the active site members at the moment.

Comment: @JohnRennie what about Carlo Rovelli?

Comment: @StanShunpike: [Carlo Rovelli was last on the site four years ago](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1613/carlo-rovelli). That's not very active.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised at the *Unclear what you're asking" close votes. It seems obvious what Mick is asking (though it's not at all clear to me that the answer is obvious).

Comment: @JohnRennie I have been trying to flag more since DavidZ said good flagging helps. This one might have been wrong. If you understand the questions, then it very well may be obvious and my flag inaccurate. I however do not understand it. As it stands, I don't know what "real" means and since that constitutes 1/3 of the question, I flagged it. Perhaps I should have suggested an edit instead of flagging?

Comment: @Kyle Kanos My definition of real is "they physically exist", as opposed to just being a computational device

Answer (score 1):

States in loop quantum gravity are the cylindrical functions, i. e. functions associated to edges and knots on a triangulated manifold. Such triangulated manifolds define the discretised space-time upon which the states (defined as above) are supposed to close a Hilbert space once a suitable scalar product is defined.

Hamiltonians, Lagrangians and all the rest can be defined starting from the corresponding Einstein-Hilbert actions and performing some sort of discretisations thereupon.

Have a look at this other [answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/208502/84488) for a broader insight and links therein to the corresponding literature. Of course, though, the complete subject is much more complicated, but this is the general underlying idea.